# No route matches [GET] "/accounts/sign_in" when use devise from mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, rails-engines

I mounted an engine to my app that uses Devise. And also I'm going to mount one more that should use it as well. So I decided to use the Devise from the first engine.

`config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount EngineWithDevise::Engine => "/engine_with_devise"
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"
end
```

All works properly but when I added the following code:

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_account!
  end
end
```

I got the following error:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/accounts/sign_in"
```

So it redirects to `/accounts/sign_in` instead of `/devise_with_engine/accounts/sign_in`

When I visit it manually is logs in successfully and then works properly.
When I mount the engine to `/` it works properly:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount EngineWithDevise::Engine => "/"
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"
end
```

According to the [manual](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine) I added the router name:

```
config.router_name = engine_with_devise
```

and did all described there.
But that didn't help.

I use the last Devise version

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging the `devise` gem I found the [commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/aa675f7f6611de5d40114aa98153f3f0c0b3e8d5) that breaks the default engine path.
So now the solution is to use Devise `3.5.1` instead of the `3.5.2` (currently the last devise version)

The issue is also described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3705)